# How to count lines of code and compare the LOC difference in one command?

Tags: diff, cloc

I'm using cloc 1.60 .

I'm wondering if that's possible to run the following two commands in one "cloc" command?

```
> cloc-1.60.exe --diff file1 file2 # returns the difference

> cloc-1.60.exe file2
```

I have to calculate the % of changed lines. I can do that by running these two commands. However I'd prefer to run them both in one command if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there currently is not a way to run both a diff and a straight
count with a single command.  I'll consider that for a future release
though.  Would be helpful if you filed a feature request
(http://sourceforge.net/p/cloc/feature-requests/?source=navbar) so 
I don't forget.

Answer (score 2):

I just committed a change that implements a new switch, `--count-and-diff`, that does the counts and diff in one shot.  It will appear in the next release.  Or you can use it now by working with the development version at https://sourceforge.net/p/cloc/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/cloc

Comment: This should have been an edit to your original answer, not a new answer.